NSNumber array containsObject fails as types are different but they should be the same
I'm having troubles checking if an array contains an object.
The @property(nonatomic) NSArray<NSNumber*>* apiArray; array is returned as a parameter from an API model while the object of which I want to check the presence in the array is returned from another API model @property(nonatomic) NSNumber* localObject;.
When I check for it [apiArray containsObject: localObject] it outputs 0 even though the value is there..
So I checked the types and on localObject the type is effectively an NSNumber, while If i'm not mistaking the array results being an NSString array as by the prints below.
            NSLog(@"$$$$$$$$$$$ [apiArray containsObject: localObject]: %d", [apiArray containsObject: localObject] );
            NSLog(@"apiArray types are: %@", [apiArray valueForKey:@"class"]);
            NSLog(@"localObject type is: %@", [localObject valueForKey:@"class"]);
            NSLog(@"apiArray is: %@", apiArray);
            NSLog(@"localObject is: %@", localObject);



$$$$$$$$$$$ [apiArray containsObject: localObject]: 0
apiArray types are: (
    "__NSCFString"
)
localObject type is: __NSCFNumber
apiArray is: (
    5717271485874176
)
localObject is: 5717271485874176
API NSNumber array types are: (
    "__NSCFString"
)

The models are generated via swagger-codegen.jar but as the parameters are shown they both seem correct.
As a test I did create an array myself and indeed the types are both NSNumber and containsObject actually works as expected
NSMutableArray<NSNumber*>* apiArray = [NSMutableArray<NSNumber*> array];
            NSNumber *localObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: -1];
            [apiArray addObject: localObject];

            NSLog(@"$$$$$$$$$$$ [apiArray containsObject: localObject]: %d", [apiArray containsObject: localObject] );
            NSLog(@"apiArray types are: %@", [apiArray valueForKey:@"class"]);
            NSLog(@"localObject type is: %@", [localObject valueForKey:@"class"]);
            NSLog(@"apiArray is: %@", apiArray);
            NSLog(@"localObject is: %@", localObject);

$$$$$$$$$$$ [apiArray containsObject: localObject]: 1
apiArray types are: (
    "__NSCFNumber"
)
localObject type is: __NSCFNumber
apiArray is: (
    "-1"
)
localObject is: -1
API NSNumber array types are: (
    "__NSCFNumber"
)

Can you spot what the problem might be?

You receive numbers in double quotes from server?

@Cy-4AH I updated the question with the prints for the values. Apparently i do get an array of NSNumber from the server, still I don't understand why the containsObject returns 0 when the object is in fact present and the type of the array prints NSString..

Your server is sending strings instead of numbers.

yes it would appear so

One is String, one is number, and to be able to "fully compare" NSNumber, I'd use integerValue instead.

@Larme I'm not sure I follow you. In my first code snippet I use the API model values, the print of the array doesn't show the value between ", its values type are NSString and containsObject returns 0.
In my second snippet I use an Array which I populate myself, and the value gets printed between ", its value types are indeed NSNumber and containsObject returns 1 correctly.
where should I use integerValue? on the object I want to know if is presente in the array from the API or where?

@Larme ok.. I did sort it out thanks to your suggestion.
I started with a BOOL containsObject set to false.
Then I loop on the array values and only  when containsObject is false (not to override an eventual match ) I compare their .integerValue  against the localObject .integerValue and assign the resulting BOOL value to containsObject itself.
It works and suits my purpose but still I can't get why the types of the array's values returned from the server are NSString when both the model and the json we receive to compile it aren't.

You could create an extension on NSArray: -(BOOL)containsWhere:(BOOL (^)(id obj))predicate { NSInteger index = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { return predicate(obj); }]; return index != NSNotFound; }, and then call it like that: BOOL contains = [array containsWhere:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj) { return [obj integerValue] == [localObject integerValue]; }];

The other API model value ( the one I want to find out if is present in the array) does compile  as an SNNumber dough

@Vincenzo How is really retrieved apiArray? In Objective-C, it's not because it's NSArray<NSNumber*>* that all element of the array will be NSNumber, it's more of a suggestion/reminder, there is in fact NO check.

To be safer in my suggestion containsWhere, call you could do if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(integerValue)]) { return [obj integerValue] == [@2 integerValue]; } else { NSLog(@"Element %@ from array to analyze doesn't responds to integerValue -> Skipped", obj); return FALSE; } else you might get a unrecognized selector sent to crash error.

@Larme OOH I see.. thanks for the clarification on the array type I found myself having to make modifications to our Objective-c app, but I'm very new to it. So the problem then might reside in the API compilation with swagger I guess. The guys from the back-end told me they send longs, not strings, and checking the json we receive to compile the API the apiArray parameter is "apiArray":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"}}.

Use xml: it doesn't have numbers in strings problem

In Objective-C, it's not because it's declared as such NSArray<NSNumber*>* apiArray that apiArray will contains only NSNumber:
NSArray<NSNumber*>* apiArray;
NSArray *t = @[@[], @"", @2];
apiArray = t;`

This will compile just fine, and the elements of apiArray are an array, a string and a number.
It's a common cause of unrecognized selector sent to instance crash error.
NSArray<NSNumber*>* apiArray is just a small helper:
It tells you that apiArray SHOULD only have NSNumber elements (even if it's not the case), so when you populate it, populate it accordingly, and when retrieving elements from it, it would expect them to be NSNumber.
So NSArray *first = [apiArray firstObject]; will produce a warning Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSArray *' with an expression of type 'NSNumber * _Nullable', but that's it, just a warning. And in my case, the first element is really a NSArray, not a NSNumber.
After a few feedbacks on your end, it seems that the back-end send NSString instead of NSNumber.
It's up to you to change it in your JSON parsing or not, or change your local model for localObject be a NSString.
If you want to keep both API/local as such, since you have NSString and NSNumber to compare, a possible way is to use integerValue.
It's a little more verbose, but this should do the trick:
NSInteger index = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    return [obj integerValue] == [localObject integerValue];
}];
BOOL contains = index != NSNotFound;

If you want to create a contains(where:) (in a more "Swift" code) you can create a category on NSArray:
NSArray+Custom.h
@interface NSArray<ObjectType> (Addon)
-(BOOL)containsWhere:(BOOL (^)(id obj))predicate;
@end

NSArray+Custom.m
@implementation NSArray (Addon)

-(BOOL)containsWhere:(BOOL (^)(id obj))predicate
{
    NSInteger index = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return predicate(obj);
    }];
    return index != NSNotFound;
}
@end

Then, in use:
NSNumber *localObject = @2;
BOOL contains = [array containsWhere:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj) {
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(integerValue)]) {
        return [obj integerValue] == [localObject integerValue];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Element %@ from array to analyze doesn't respond to integerValue -> Skipped", obj);
        return FALSE;
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@ contains localObject: %d", array, localObject, contains);


Oh wow! Thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate the in-depth
explanation. I did check-out again with the back-end guys and indeed they're sending an array of strings..dough it shouldn't and they're looking into it because it shouldn't be the case looking at the OpenAPi yaml they're using to generate the endpoints

Meanwhile I was just looking in to making an extension on NSArray to solve the problem as my for loop solution isn't the most elegant way to solve it, so once again thanks for the gigantic help
